# Как обращаться к серверу каждые 5 секунд?

Tags: java, android

Дело в том что до сегодняшнего дня я для общения с сервером использовал `Volley` и каждые определенные время отправлял запрос. Но теперь мне предстоит решить не стандартную задачу. То есть, нужно проверять данные пришли или нет с сервера, отправил собеседник сообщение или нет. Каждые 5 секунд проверять базу, отправлять запросы даже если нет сообщений мне кажется не правильно, да еще где то читал что этот вариант больше жрет аккумулятор.

Вопрос: Есть ли решение, которое меньше использует аккумулятор, и проверяет сервер в реальном времени? Если да, скиньте ссылку на туториалы...

Comment: Нынче `Socket` отменили? - Стабильнее чем через `Socket` никак.

Comment: Используйте [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).

Answer (score 0):

В своём учебном проекте я делаю так:

У меня есть на сервере и клиенте `WebSocket'ы`(На сервере веб-сокет от `Jetty`, а на клиенте от `OkHttp`), они общаются между собой через `JSON` (Использую Gson).

На клиенте в веб-сокете каждое новое сообщение добавляется в очередь (`Queue`). Есть ещё пару методов, которые возвращают размер очереди и извлекают объект из неё.

Затем в нужном классе при помощи `RxJava` и метода `interval`, я проверяю кол-во сообщений, и если сообщений больше чем 0, я их все извлекаю.

Возможно реализация выглядит глупа, но работает как надо.

P.S. Сокет создаётся единожды при старте приложения в [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) А в нужном классе я подключаюсь к нему.